# PHP: Issue with add hours

Tags: php

I need to get a datetime field from MySQL and add it two (2) hours to show it in PHP.

I've tried with this, but doesn't work:

```
foreach ($player->select($id) as $element) {

    echo date($element['date'], time('+2 hours'));

}
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: `echo date($element['date'], strtotime('+2 hours'));`

Comment: Your use of `time` is incorrect, please refer to php doc

Comment: @Syscall crap, it's actually `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($element['date']." +2 hours"));`

Comment: @ishegg Right :) Mine was also wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should actually be

```
foreach ($player->select($id) as $element) {
    $time = strtotime($element['date']);
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 hours', $time));
}
```

`strtotime`'s 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter takes a time parameter which is used to calculate relative times. [Php Manual on strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)